# better way to use link_to on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need use this gem https://github.com/potatosalad/mongoid-data_table.

This is my model code:

```
class Admin
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  include Mongoid::DataTable
  #datatableblock
  ## data_table ##
  data_table_options.merge!({
    :fields => %w(id email created_at role actions),
    :searchable => %w(email role),
    :dataset => lambda do |admin|
      {
        0 => "<%= check_box_tag \"admin_ids[]\", admin._id, false, :class => \"check\" %>",
        1 => admin.id,
        2 => "<%= link_to(admin.email, admin_admin_path(admin._id)) %>",
        3 => admin.created_at,
        4 => admin.role,
        5 => "<%= link_to(I18n.t('admin.actions.show'), admin_admin_path(admin._id)) %> - <%= link_to(I18n.t('admin.actions.edit'), edit_admin_admin_path(admin._id)) %> - <%= link_to I18n.t('admin.actions.delete'), admin_admin_path(admin._id)%>",
        :DT_RowId => admin._id
      }
    end
  })
end
```

I know this action likely violating some principle of the Model-View-Controller architecture.

I need use `link_to` and ruby on rails code to generate correct content inside each columns.

**Then my question is: How can I do it in a better way without violating the principles of MVC?**

Thank you very much

Comment: That is the way to use that gem.  The other way would be to not use mongoid-data_table.

Comment: Agree with comment above: MVC is an approach to structuring your code that solves many common problems.  Not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That gem is a specialized use-case and may be suitable if you don't want to add another class or layer to your application, but it does violate MVC.

The correct implementation (imo) of what that gem is trying to do is the [Presenter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter#Pattern_description).

There are many gems for Rails which implement the same. Basically, this code should be in a custom class, and not in the model file.

Watch [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables) by Ryan Bates to get a clear picture of how to do this without any gems and more importantly the addition of presenters in MVC.

When you use presenters, decorators or other design patterns in tandem with MVC, they should not and do not typically violate the core architecture.

Comment: Thank you very much! but Ryan Bates way is with Active-Record. I need a way with mongoid. Thank you

Comment: @hyperrjas the ORM doesn't change the way the solution is implemented...  the **fetch_products** method he has defined just needs to use the Mongoid ORM / query syntax and it will all work perfectly!

Comment: @hyperrjas the key take away was how to create a custom presenter class, use it to fetch records, return semi-formatted data as json and delegating certain methods to the view.... like __link_to__

Comment: Thank you very much! I will check ryan bates solution! If you can add an example how it works ryan bates fix for `Mongoid` would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If it is going to break MVC, perhaps the best thing would be to put it into a module in your /lib folder and load it as an include instead of inline with the rest of your code. This would also help maintain one responsibility for your Model. Perhaps something like this?

```
class Admin
  include Admin::CustomDatatable
end

module Admin
  module CustomDataTable
    data_table_options.merge!({
      :fields => %w(id email created_at role actions),
      :searchable => %w(email role),
       :dataset => lambda do |admin|
         {
           0 => "<%= check_box_tag \"admin_ids[]\", admin._id, false, :class => \"check\" %>",
           1 => admin.id,
           2 => "<%= link_to(admin.email, admin_admin_path(admin._id)) %>",
           3 => admin.created_at,
           4 => admin.role,
           5 => "<%= link_to(I18n.t('admin.actions.show'), admin_admin_path(admin._id)) %> - <%= link_to(I18n.t('admin.actions.edit'), edit_admin_admin_path(admin._id)) %> - <%= link_to I18n.t('admin.actions.delete'), admin_admin_path(admin._id)%>",
    :DT_RowId => admin._id
         }
      end
    })
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. The idea is good but is not working fine with this gem. I get error when I try run rails server. The method `data_table_options` is not working outside the model.